# How to change the color of light in three.js using simple GUI?

Tags: three.js

I intend to create an app that changes the color of reflected light by using the slider created via three.js GUI.

The HTML code I used to change the color of light at her will is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>How to put GUI in three.js app?</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        
        <!-- MODULE option is more difficult to use in this simple setup:
        <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js"></script>
        -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lil-gui@0.17"></script>

        <script>

            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );
            camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );
            
            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


            const geometry2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 50, 32, 16 );
            const texture2 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://i.imgur.com/P4PQzYk.jpg' );
            const material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: texture2 } );
            const sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );
            
            scene.add( sphere2 );
            sphere2.position.set(100, 0, -500); 


             function greenDoge(newGreen) 
            {
            const green = newGreen;
            let colorofsun = new THREE.Color ("rgb( 255, green, 255");
            const light = new THREE.PointLight( colorofsun , 2, 5000, 2 );
            light.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
            if (scene) {
              scene.remove(light)
            }
            scene.add( light );
            }
                
            greenDoge(10);


            const GUI = lil.GUI;
            const gui = new GUI();

            const params = {
              green: 0
 
            }

            const folderDoge = gui.addFolder( 'Change Color' );
            folderDoge.add( params, 'green', 0, 255, 1).onChange( greenDoge );   
            folderDoge.open();



            const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.update();

            function animate() 
            {
                sphere2.rotation.x += 0.00;
                sphere2.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            };
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The HTML code did work, but when I tried to adjust the color of the light, the sphere remains white and the web browser becomes noticeably slower.

I don't know where I messed up. I couldn't find any reason why the sphere can't change color when I slide the slider GUI.

What is the reason why the color didn't change?

How do we also modify the code such that the color can be changed to our will? Any hints will be very welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there are very obvious errors in your code.
You're missing a closing bracket in your `new THREE.Color` constructor call and also you're trying to use a variable in a string, which will not work.
so this:

```js
 let colorofsun = new THREE.Color ("rgb( 255, green, 255");
```

should more look like this:

```js
 let colorofsun = new THREE.Color ("rgb( 255, " + green + ", 255 )");
```

Fixing this however does not fix your problem as there are many other issues. I think you should start reading more [documentation](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master) and code samples.

but lets stick to your problem:

in your `greenDoge` function, you're creating a new instance of `PointLight` and after that you want to remove it from the scene. this will never work as a new created light cannot be in the scene without adding it first.

You would need to give your light a name to remove it and update your materials to have it added for that to work. You might want to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879378/adding-and-removing-three-js-lights-at-run-time).

However adding and removing the light every time the color changes is not necessary at all.

What you could do instead is just adding the light once and update its color like this:

```js
let colorofsun = new THREE.Color ("rgb( 255, 255, 255)");
var light = new THREE.PointLight( colorofsun , 2, 5000, 2 );
light.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
scene.add( light );


function greenDoge(newGreen) 
{
    light.color.setRGB(1, newGreen, 1);
}
```

note that the `setRGB` function is using values from 0 to 1. so you need to change your slider values accordingly.

```js
folderDoge.add( params, 'green', 0, 1, 0.1).onChange( greenDoge );
```

You can read more about that on the [github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Color.js) page of threejs.